# Regex in R: How to sub() multiple column values at once?

Tags: r, regex, pattern-matching

I'm trying to make the following script more concise.

```
SH1$SCORING7_01 = sub("-", "", SH1$SCORING7_01)    
SH1$SCORING7_02 = sub("-", "", SH1$SCORING7_02)    
SH1$SCORING7_03 = sub("-", "", SH1$SCORING7_03)    
SH1$SCORING7_04 = sub("-", "", SH1$SCORING7_04)    
SH1$SCORING7_05 = sub("-", "", SH1$SCORING7_05)
```

Essentially I'm just removing a '-' from each column's values.  (This is part of a larger process.)
Is there a way that I could sub() the '-' from all five column's values at the same time?
The number of these specific 'SCORING_XX' columns actually goes up to 38 and could increase in the future. So something involving a column range would be great (example: SCORING7_01:SCORING7_XX).

I'm running "R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12)" on Windows

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R option:

```
names <- c("SCORING7_01", "SCORING7_02", "SCORING7_03", "SCORING7_04", "SCORING7_05")
SH1[names] <- lapply(SH1[names], function(x) sub("-", "", x, fixed=TRUE))
```

Note that I use the `fixed=TRUE` option in the above call to `sub`, as your replacement logic does not actually involve any regular expression.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for this. Is there anyway that I can grab those 'SCORING7_0X' and list them out instead?  For example, I tried an index range, names <- SH1[c(1:5)] , but could not get this to work. It would be better if I could get something like names <- SH1[c("SCORING7_01":"SCORING7_05")] .  The point of wanting a 'range' is because the number of these SCORING7_columns could be much, much higher. So listing them out individually like you did takes some time.  Thanks!

Comment: @aduran3 Yes, use `grepl`: `names[grepl("^SCORING7_", names)]`

Comment: Hi Tim, where would the grepl line go?  Sorry, having some issues with this.

Answer (score 0):

## data.table

With `data.table`, you could use `.SD` and `lapply`:

```r
dt <- data.table(df)
dt[,lapply(.SD, function(x) sub("-","",x)), .SDcols = paste0("SCORING7_0",1:5)]
```

## base R

You can also use a base `R` solution

```r
df[,paste0("SCORING7_0",1:5)] <- lapply(paste0("SCORING7_0",1:7), function(var) sub("-","",df[,var]))
```

Comment: Thanks linog.  Question: what are you referring to with 1:7 ? Thanks again.

Comment: That's a concise way of generating your columns since they all have the same pattern. I made a typo by goiing UP to 7 rather than 5, I change that in m'y edit